# PL-SQL loop throug values to get dynamic query and store results

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got code as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE cat_array_t is varray(2) of varchar(10);
--    cat_array cat_array_t:=cat_array_t('retired','worker');
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Data_Faster(in_cat IN cat_array, in_kw_crt IN kw_crt_array) RETURN get_data_faster_data PIPELINED AS
    TYPE r_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    query_results r_cursor;
    results_out get_data_faster_row := get_data_faster_row(NULL, NULL);

    query_str VARCHAR2(4000);

    cat_value VARCHAR2(10);
    kw_crt_value VARCHAR2(10);
    

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..cat_array.COUNT
    LOOP
        cat_value := cat_array(i);
        kw_crt_value := kw_crt_array(i);
        

--        query_str := 'SELECT distinct '||seq_number||' as seq, value, item
--        FROM my_table ai';                    
--
--        query_str := query_str || '
--        WHERE ai.value = '''||the_value||''' AND ai.item = '''||the_item||'''
--        AND ai.param = ''BOOK''
--        AND ai.prod in (' || list || ');
        
         query_str := 'select owner_id,property_id ' ||
               'from owners ' ||
               'where substr(PROPERTY_ID,1,4) =' || chr(39) || kw_crt_value     || chr(39) ||
               '  and Owner_category    = ' || chr(39) || cat_value || chr(39);

        OPEN query_results FOR query_str;

        LOOP
            FETCH query_results INTO 
                results_out.owner_id,
                results_out.property_id;
            EXIT WHEN query_results%NOTFOUND;
            PIPE ROW(results_out);
        END LOOP;

    CLOSE query_results;

    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

The problem is when I run this I get error.
In log there is "Error: PLS-00201: identifier "CAT_ARRAY" should be declared". Don't how to improve this code. How to pass this line with elements of varray to code
--    cat_array cat_array_t:=cat_array_t('retired','worker');

Comment: "I tried declare this on the beginning" -  does that mean you add the type declaration to the code you showed because you got this error, and you already have the SQL type defined? If so should `IN cat_array` just be `IN cat_array_t`?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE cat_array_t ...
```

but then your function has

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Data_Faster(in_cat IN cat_array, ...
```

The type name doesn't match; it should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Data_Faster(in_cat IN cat_array_t, ...
```

and you don't need/want the separate local PL/SQL type declaration, or the local variable; and you need to refer to the passed-in parameter name (as @Boneist beat me too):

```
FOR i IN 1..in_cat.COUNT
```

You may have done the same thing with `in_kw_crt IN kw_crt_array`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you're referencing your array with (almost) the name of the type, not the name of the array, e.g.:

```
FOR i IN 1..cat_array.COUNT
```

should be

```
FOR i IN 1..in_cat.COUNT
```

since you have defined the name of the parameter as in_cat here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Data_Faster(in_cat IN cat_array_t, ....
                                           ^^^^^^
```

You must replace all instances of the variable name `cat_array` with the correct name `in_cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it returns an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Data_Faster (in_cat IN cat_array)
   RETURN NUMBER                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ type is used here
IS
   TYPE cat_array_t IS VARRAY (2) OF VARCHAR (10);    --> type is declared here
   cat_array cat_array_t:=cat_array_t('emeryt','pracownik');
```

You're first referencing a type which is declared **within** the function. You can't do that; create type at SQL level, not within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your type `cat_array` and `cat_array_t` must be SQL type defined as an individual as follows:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE ] TYPE type_name AS | IS
    VARRAY(max_elements) OF element_type [NOT NULL];
```

Now, this type can be used globally in your PL/SQL code.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code but still error is the same. How to pass list of varray's element into the code?

Comment: While calling the function from PL/SQL, You need to create the variable of the `cat_array` and input them into function IN parameter.